# Get class and call method of it by string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have value in `appsettings.json` where I have matching strategy, it's string

Also I have class that have same name

Here is sample

```
public class FuzzyCompanyNameStrategy : MatchingScoreCalculationStrategy
{
    public override int CalculateScore(ScoreInputModel input, SupplierModel supplier) =>
        Fuzz.Ratio(input.CompanyName, supplier.SupplierNameNormalized);
}
```

I code where I need to get this class and method, I have input parameter -  name of this Class but it's string.

Here is this class

```
 protected async Task<MatchingScoreOutput> FindMatch(string name, string postalCode, string city, string matchingStrategy)
        {
            try
            {
                string comparisonName = ComparablePropsHelper.GetComparableCompanyName(name);
                string comparisonPostalCode = ComparablePropsHelper.GetComparablePostalCode(postalCode);
                string comparisonCity = ComparablePropsHelper.GetComparableCityName(city);

                var jobSuppliers = await _dataPipelineDbContext.JobSuppliers.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
                
               
                
                return new MatchingScoreOutput
                {
                    MatchFound = true,
                    Confidence = MatchConfidence.HIGH,
                    Score = ,
                };
 }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex,
                    $"{nameof(GenericScoreSupplierComparisonService<TEntity>)}: Exception occurred. Message: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
```

In  `Score =` I need somehow to call strategy that coming from `matchingStrategy` and call `CalculateScore`

How I can do this?

Comment: What does this class have to do with my question? @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: **Firstly,** you are trying to call `CalculateScore` of return type of `int`, so need to check what type of property `Score` is.

**Secondly,** thinking if  `FuzzyCompanyNameStrategy`  can be intiniated within `FindMatch` method just before  new instance of `MatchingScoreOutput`. So that if value can be contained on a variable then pass that inside the `score` am I clear?

Comment: 1) Score is `int`
2) I have 3 different classes with different name and with same name  of method, so point is get class by string coming from config @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Alright try what @Tony suggested. Hope it would help you to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways to do this
Use System.Reflection
Get the assembly where the types are defined.
The Assembly class has a GetType method which takes a string and will return the type.
Create an instance of the type, cast it as MatchingScoreCalulationStrategy and call the method.
It can get very fiddly this. Personally I prefer to use attributes, then name of the strategy doesn't have to be the class name.